# How to change `object_name` of a model in Django

Tags: python, django

I have an object `LeatherChair` in Django, and it pisses me off that Django gives it an `object_name` of `leatherchair`. I want it to be `leather_chair`, with an underscore.

The `object_name` seems to be stored in the `Options` instance, but how do I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to change `object_name` is a really bad idea. It is set in the `Model._meta` as you say, but it is not one of the documented [available Meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/). Trying to change it risks breaking stuff.

I don't understand why it is so important to change it. It's not displayed publicly, so it doesn't really matter whether it has an underscore or not. In the comment below you point out that `object_name` is used by the CBV, but I would use the documented ways to change `context_object_name` in the CBV instead of trying to change it on the model

If you must change it on the model, you probably need to hack around in [`django.db.models.options`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/options.py). You could try monkey patching `DEFAULT_PARAMS`, to allow you to set `object_name` in the model `Meta` class.

Comment: It does matter in several places, for example the object context name used by class based views. I can change it on the CBV, but I'd prefer to change in on the model itself.

Comment: OK, I hadn't thought of the CBV. I've updated my answer. Good luck.